# Integrate a versioning in aggregate

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, version-numbering

I want to integrate a version field into my aggregate for the consistency and integrity of my data.

I would like to have feedback on the different implementation and architecture knowing that I do not use event sourcing.

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Comment: not really an ORM , but i’am using dapper as Micro ORM